# Using Python to draw a mosaic/marimekko plot in plotly bar gap issue

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, marimekko-chart

I would like to use plotly to generate a mosaic plot in python. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76016121/using-python-to-draw-a-mosaic-marimekko-chart-with-custom-colors-and-labels/76031810#76031810) answer, but there's a gap between the bar charts I can't get rid of. I've tried using `fig.update_layout(bargap=0)` but that doesn't fix it. Is there a way to fix this so that the bars touch or are at least closer to one another?

Plot with gap between bars

[image: Plot with gap between bars]

Code and data I'm using

```
# Dataframe creation/formatting
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [5755, 6221, 5424, 7261, 1158, 7075, 6780],
        [6103, 3143, 7094, 9212, 3175, 9956, 9655],
        [2810, 3047, 5938, 2067, 2189, 8892, 2380],
    ],
    columns=['X1','X2','X3','X4','X5','X6','X7']
)

df = df.T

labels = ['Group1','Group2','Group3']

df.columns = labels

for c in df.columns:
    df[c + '_%'] = df[c].apply(lambda x: (x/df.loc[:,c].sum()) * 100)
    

widths = np.array([sum(df['Group1']),sum(df['Group2']),sum(df['Group3'])])

marker_colors = {
    'X1':'darkblue',
    'X2':'darkgreen',
    'X3':'crimson',
    'X4':'green',
    'X5':'blue',
    'X6':'red',
    'X7':'orange'
}


fig1 = go.Figure()

for idx in df.index:
    dff = df.filter(items=[idx], axis=0)
    fig1.add_trace(go.Bar(
        x=np.cumsum(widths) - widths,
        y=dff[dff.columns[3:]].values[0],
        width=widths,
        marker_color=marker_colors[idx],
        text=['{:.2f}%'.format(x) for x in dff[dff.columns[3:]].values[0]],
        name=idx
    )
)

fig1.update_xaxes(
    tickvals=np.cumsum(widths)-widths,
    ticktext= ["%s<br>%d" % (l, w) for l, w in zip(labels, widths)]
)

fig1.update_xaxes(range=[0, widths])
fig1.update_yaxes(range=[0, 100])

fig1.update_layout(barmode='stack')

#fig1.write_image('test_1.png')
fig1.show()
```

I tried to create a mosaic plot in plotly following a guide posted in another thread. The resulting plot has gaps between the bars that I cannot remove. I've tried using `fig.update_layout(bargap=0)` but that doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things to fix :

- Set `offset=0` to every bar traces.
- Fix the xaxis `range` and `tickvals` accordingly (see below).

```py
fig1 = go.Figure()

for idx in df.index:
    dff = df.filter(items=[idx], axis=0)
    fig1.add_trace(go.Bar(
        x=np.cumsum(widths) - widths,
        y=dff[dff.columns[3:]].values[0],
        width=widths,
        marker_color=marker_colors[idx],
        text=['{:.2f}%'.format(x) for x in dff[dff.columns[3:]].values[0]],
        name=idx,
        offset=0
    )
)

fig1.update_yaxes(range=[0, 100])
fig1.update_xaxes(
    range=[0, np.sum(widths)],
    tickvals=np.cumsum(widths) - widths/2,
    ticktext= ["%s<br>%d" % (l, w) for l, w in zip(labels, widths)]
)

fig1.update_layout(barmode='stack')

fig1.show()
```

[image: output]